# adding anchor to mouseover event in Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to add an anchor to a `mouseover` event in Raphael, so that it doesn't trigger the `mouseout` when its hovered over,

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ty7D/2/) to better show what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a working jsfiddle, using the last example below.](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/pXuhp/1/)

To do this purely with Raphael, it's going to be complex. Here's the basic idea:

- in the mouseout event, use `Element.isPointInside()` to determine if the mouseout was triggered by the link or by leaving the box
- you can use event.target; event is passed into the mouseout callback
- if it is triggered by the link, then simply ignore the mouseout (you'll get another when it leaves the actual box)
- in the mousein event, make sure you only trigger it if coming from outside the box (when user comes back from the link, you'll get another mousein event)

Another alternative in Raphael would be to draw a transparent box over both link and background, and use that to trigger the mouse events--including the click; this would greatly reduce the complexity.

If you want to cheat a little, and not reinvent any wheels here, you could use an existing solution and integrate that into Raphael's code. For instance, you can use jQuery to trigger the event with something like this:

```
jQuery('#button').on('mouseenter', function() { xxd.stop().animate(...) }
jQuery('#button').on('mouseleave', function() { xxd.stop().animate(...) }
```

And going a step farther in that vein, there's really no reason to manage this in Raphael. Just use Raphael to create and manage the background image, and leave the rest in jQuery or your favorite lib.